# Share a string or part of page on Facebook

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, wordpress, facebook

I want to share a part of a page with Facebook ... this should be easy keeping in mind the scale of Facebook and the research that has been put into it. I have below loop which is fetching data from a $wpdb->select query and at the end of the loop I want a Facebook button but on click only that particular row of my MySQL table should be shared on Facebook. I know about https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button to get the Facebook share code but how can I use this to share only the current value of my loop. Thanks any idea !! Below is my query and foreach loop ... I am not getting hold of it how this can be done.

PHP Code

```
global $wpdb;
$sqll = "SELECT articles.aid, articles.username, articles.competition, articles.path, articles.category, articles.title, SUBSTR(articles.body, 1, 512) As articlebody, articles.body, Sum(zvotes.zvotes) AS votessum FROM articles LEFT JOIN zvotes on articles.aid=zvotes.aid WHERE articles.category = '$cat' && articles.competition = '$comp' GROUP BY articles.aid, articles.username, articles.competition, articles.path, articles.category, articles.title ORDER BY articles.aid DESC";

$results = $wpdb->get_results($sqll) or die(mysql_error());
$response=array();
 if( is_array($results) && count($results) > 0  )
 $form="";

foreach( $results as $result ) {
$form.= '<form id="voteform" action="" method="post">';
$form.= "<input id='aid' name='aid' type='text' value='$result->aid'>";
$form.= "<div id='tsm'></div>".'<br>';
$form.= "<input id='category' name='category' type='hidden' value='$result->category'>"; 
$form.= "Title :".$result->title.'<br>';
$form.= "<div class='mg-image' style='margin-top:15px;'><img id='articlecontest' src='$result->path' width='250' height='250' ></div>" . '<br><br>';
$form.= "<input id='competition' name='competition' type='hidden' value='$result->competition'>";
$form.= "Username :".$result->username.'<br>';
$form.= "<input id='sumofvotes' name='sumofvotes' type='hidden' value='$result->votessum'>";
$form.= "<div class='myvotes'><div id='total'>"."Total Votes:".$result->votessum."</div></div>".'<br>';
$form.= "<div id='articlesummary'>".$result->articlebody."</div>";
$form.="<div id='clickme' style='color:blue; font-size:16px; font-family: Satisfy, Cursive;'>".'READ MORE'."</div>";
$form.= '<div id="articlebody">'.'This is body text'.$result->body.'</div>';
///////////////
$form.="<input class='star' id='star1' type='image' type='submit' name='star5' src='http://localhost:8080/test/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/checkmark-small-unfilled.png' value='1' style='border:0px!important;'>";
$form.="<input class='star' id='star2' type='image' type='submit' name='star5' src='http://localhost:8080/test/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/checkmark-small-unfilled.png' value='2' style='border:0px!important;'>";
$form.="<input class='star' id='star3' type='image' type='submit' name='star5' src='http://localhost:8080/test/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/checkmark-small-unfilled.png' value='3' style='border:0px!important;'>";
$form.="<input class='star' id='star4' type='image' type='submit' name='star5' src='http://localhost:8080/test/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/checkmark-small-unfilled.png' value='4' style='border:0px!important;'>";
$form.="<input class='star' class='star' id='star5'  type='image' type='submit'  name='star5' src='http://localhost:8080/test/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/checkmark-small-unfilled.png' value='5' style='border:0px!important;'></form>";
///////////////

}//end of foreach
$response['form']=$form;
    echo json_encode($response['form']);
    exit();

}
///////////////////////////////////
add_action( 'wp_ajax_star', 'star' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_star', 'star');
```

Comment: anybody with any idea

Comment: Would you mind please provide more context about what you want to share? is it a post? a group of posts? you should be able to use the share plugin even with dynamic content generated urls. If you can provide more context on what exactly you want to do we might be able to provide some help. So far I can see a loop that generates multiple forms... not sure what to do with that :P